# UWP WinRTXamlToolkit: chart-labels with units

Tags: charts, label, win-universal-app, axis, toolkit

For an UWP-app I'm displaying a chart with height data and it currently looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to have units for the y-values like `100 m`, but I can only manage to get the value itself.
I am able to put a static unit behind that value by "StringFormat" in the "AxisLabelStyle" like this

```
<Setter Property="StringFormat" Value="{}{0:0 m}" />
```

but unfortunately I need a dynamic unit (e.g. meters or feet).

Am I missing anything? Ideas?

Comment: when change from meters to feet, what trigger (e.g. button click events or size changed event) do you need to make it happen? Or you want it all by random?

Comment: That is a user-setting within a settings-page apart form the chart, so I got that information before creating the chart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've discussed, this style is set by user. So I just use a `ComboBox` to select the style for test.

Here is my code:

```xml
<Charting:Chart x:Name="AreaChart" Title="Area Chart" Margin="0,0">
    <Charting:AreaSeries x:Name="areaseries" IndependentValuePath="Value" DependentValuePath="Number" IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
</Charting:Chart>

<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>Meters</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Feet</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

code behind is just for testing, I didn't tried to rebuild your chart in your picture:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadChartContents();
}

private void LoadChartContents()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    List<ChartTest> testitem = new List<ChartTest>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        testitem.Add(new ChartTest() { Value = i, Number = rand.Next(0, 100) });
    }

    (AreaChart.Series[0] as AreaSeries).ItemsSource = testitem;
}

private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    areaseries.IndependentAxis = new LinearAxis { Orientation = AxisOrientation.X };
    var axis = (LinearAxis)areaseries.IndependentAxis;
    var item = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if ((string)item.Content == "Meters")
    {
        var labelstyle = new Style(typeof(AxisLabel));
        labelstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(AxisLabel.StringFormatProperty, "{0:0 m}"));
        axis.AxisLabelStyle = labelstyle;
    }
    else
    {
        var labelstyle = new Style(typeof(AxisLabel));
        labelstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(AxisLabel.StringFormatProperty, "{0:0 feet}"));
        axis.AxisLabelStyle = labelstyle;
    }
}
```

And my is `ChartTest` class like this:

```cs
public class ChartTest
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

The key point here is dynamic adding `AxisLabelStyle` to `AreaSeries` in the `SelectionChanged` event of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!